Customizing the Record Level Actions of Interactive Grid with Oracle Apex
In the Interactive Grid I have List of records having 'ID', 'Name', 'FK_ID' columns. I want to add an action into the record level actions which appears next into IG rows, so I can redirect into other page and passing the ID and FK_ID parameters of that record into the page.
How I customize the actions of the record action menu not the main IG Action Menu as what mostly explained?

This video explains what I want How To Add Row Level Actions.
Simply, add two global variables into the page ig_grid for Interactive Grid region view and ig_model for the Interactive Grid model.
then, add Page Change [Interactive Grid] Dynamic Action into the grid region that includes this Execute Javascript Code Action and set its code to this:
ig_grid = apex.region('ig_static_id').call("getViews", "grid");
ig_model = ig_grid.model;

rowOptions = ig_grid.rowActionMenu$.menu("option").items;
if (!rowOptions.some(obj => obj.id === 'show-details')) {
rowOptions.push({
    type: "action",
    label: "Show Details",
    id: "show-details",
    action: function (event, focusElement) {
        const savingPromise = apex.model.save(null, null, students_model.modelId()) ?? Promise.resolve(null);
        savingPromise.then(
            function redirectToPage() {
                let record = ig_grid.getContextRecord(focusElement)[0]
                var record_id = record[9] // the column order is 9 in IG model
                var record_fk_id = record[2] // the column order is 2 in IG model

                var parameters_names = "P100_ID,P100_FK_ID"
                var parameters_values = record_id + "," + record_fk_id
                var url = "f?p=" + apex.env.APP_ID + ":" + 100+ ":" + apex.env.APP_SESSION + "::::" + parameters_names + ":" + parameters_values;
                apex.navigation.redirect(url);
            });

    }
})
}


the condition !rowOptions.some(obj => obj.id === 'show-details') to prevent adding the action multiple times whe the region refreshed.
Note:
Set the Dynamic Action to Page Load instead of Page Change [Interactive Grid] if you faced any problems in region initialization.

Note that this solution only works if there is no security on the target page 100. If the page is protected with checksums then this will fail. In that case use an AJAX process to generate the url using apex_page.get_url
